# How to simply validate a checkbox in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, checkbox

How do you simply validate that a checkbox is checked in rails?
The checkbox is for a end user agreement. And it is located in a modal window.

Lets say i have the checkbox:

```
<%= check_box_tag '' %>
```

Where and how should i validate this?

I have seen most posts about checkbox validation in rails here, but none of them suit my needs.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding

```
validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true
```

to your model should do it. Look [**here**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance) for more details and options.

However, if accepting the terms is not part of a form for your model, you should use client-side validations, i.e. JavaScript, like this (in jQuery):

```
function validateCheckbox()
{
    if( $('#checkbox').attr('checked')){
      alert("you have to accept the terms first");
    }
}
```

You can add a script file to your view like this:

`<%= javascript_include_tag "my_javascipt_file" %>`

and trigger the function on click:

`<%= submit_tag "Submit", :onclick: "validateCheckbox();" %>`

EDIT: you can assign an id to your checkbox like this: `check_box_tag :checkbox`. The HTML will look like this: `<input id="checkbox"` See [**these examples**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag) for more options.

Comment: In that case, how would i "name" the checkbox?

Comment: kostja delivers quite a nice explaination, however I personally prefer doing the acceptance validation both client-side and in my controllers, then if accepted I submit the current time for lets say a User model to its "accepted_conditions_at" attribute that way I can easily maintain and let user re-accept my terms of conditions if they change for some reason

Comment: Okay. I have now added 'validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true' to my model like the rest of the validations. My "submit"-button looks like this '<%= link_to 'Submit', "#", :class => "btn btn-primary", :onclick => "$('##{dom_id(@confession)}').submit()" %>'. It is working, but how do i add the jQuery "validation" as a check  for the submit-button? Sorry, i havent done much javascript/jQuery.

Comment: @user2019492 - have added some more details, hope it clarifies the issue

Answer (score 3):

I was able to skip the jQuery portion and get it validation to work with this questions help. My method is below, I'm on Rails 5.1.2 & Ruby 2.4.2.

Put this code in your slim, erb or haml; note syntax may differ slightly in each.
The line below was specifically for slim.

```
f.check_box :terms_of_service, required: true
```

I used a portion of kostja's code suggestion in the model.

```
validates :terms_of_service, :acceptance => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to what has been said already, if you want to add a custom error message, you can add the following to your form:

```
f.input :terms_of_service, as: :boolean
```

and then add the following to your model:

```
validates :terms_of_service, acceptance: { message: "must be accepted"}
```

Error messages will start with the field name by default followed by your custom message (e.g. Terms of service [CUSTOM MESSAGE]). Something I also found useful was to include a link to the terms of service in the label so users can easily access it to see what they are agreeing to:

```
f.input :terms_of_service, as: :boolean, label: "I agree to the #{link_to "terms of service", [TERMS AND CONDITIONS PATH]}".html_safe
```