# Ruby on Rails 3 checkbox validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
- @offering.training.each do |train|
    = check_box_tag "train_ids[#{train.id}]", train.id
    = train.text
```

Model:

```
class Training < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text

  belongs_to :offering

 validates :text, presence: true 
end
```

How do you validate checkboxes in rails 3? The following code doesn't work at the moment. I would appreciate your help guys. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to simply validate a checkbox in rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16237734/how-to-simply-validate-a-checkbox-in-rails)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a simple checkbox that you want to validate as being checked, use:

```
validates :some_checkbox, :acceptance => true
```

If you have a list of checkboxes or otherwise want something more complicated, set up a custom validator method in your controller:

```
validate :custom_checkbox_validation

def custom_checkbox_validation
  unless (your condition) errors.add(:base, "your error message") 
end
```